# How to use webworks 2.0 to call a https services using http request of javascript

Tags: blackberry-10, webwork

I am having a task to call a https request using http request api of javascript. Need help to implement it. And also ,is there any other way to see the output without going for a blackberry simulator for a project created using webworks.

Comment: Consider asking one question (you're asking 2 in your post) and posting the code which you've already tried.

Comment: i didnt even get the any idea for code ,educate me with some idea. Those are related question so please answer any one of the question.